# removing pseudo element ::after using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know is there a way to remove the pseudo ::after. I cant show in code but I have image to explain.

[image: image1]

When selecting a checkbox from `::before` a `::after` will be added now What I want is when selecting another checkbox the other checkbox will lose `::after` and will be back to `::before`

[image: iamge2]

What I tried is

`$('.ckbox label').not(this).removeAttr('::after');`

But it is not removing the `::after` I can say that it is not removing because the style is still there

Comment: Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608023/removing-an-element-added-by-before-pseudo-selector)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing an element added by ::before pseudo selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608023/removing-an-element-added-by-before-pseudo-selector)

Comment: @DanielBeck i tried it it is not working because there is still the `::after` so I rreally need to find a way to remove it.. I will try triggering the click for other checkbox maybe it work. is there a drawback if i trigger many checkbox at once?

Comment: I do not understand what you're saying in that comment at all.  If you want to remove content added in a ::before or ::after pseudoclass, you need to do that in CSS (by setting the pseudoclass `content` to an empty string).  You can't clear it with "`removeAttr()`" because it is not an attribute, it's a pseudoclass.

Comment: @DanielBeck i mean when there is the psuedo :after in the element the state of the element is still check i need to remove it so that the state will be uncheck because I need to only be able to select only 1 from the checkbox. I will try to use radio button but i cant test it now maybe later.

Comment: You need to change the state of the checkbox?  That has nothing to do with the contents of ::after.  `$('#checkbox1').prop('checked', false);` (or true as needed.)

Comment: But, yes, if the reason you were trying to do this was to enforce that only one is checked at a time, you would definitely want to be using a radio button for that instead.

Comment: `$('#checkbox1').prop('checked', false);` i also have that but in the design the checkbox looks like it is still ticked.

Comment: changing checkbox to radio solved it @DanielBeck

Answer (score 4):

You can't target pseudo elements this way. However you could add a class that sets the content to "none", or add a class and add the pseudo element that way, then just remove the class when you no longer want it.

```
.added-class:after {
  content:none
}
```

---

```
$('.ckbox label').addClass('added-class');
```